# How to simply fill a TableView for iPhone

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have got an UITableView. How to *simply* fill it with three elements, for example "e1", "e2", "e3" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set DataSource of your table to your class and define in your class 3 methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *cellId = @"identifier";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellId];
  if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellId] autorelease];
  }
  [cell setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"e%i",indexPath:[indexPath row]];
  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableView is a component that rewards study. Read the local doc pages on UITableView and its datasource and delegate protocols. 
There is a table view programming guide in the docs as well. It is a good read. 
Some of it took me a while to grok and I am still refining my approach each time I implement one.
Using the API and implementing the methods it requires, you should be able to bend it to your will.

Hellra1ser's example should push you in the right direction. Lookup those methods first, you will be using them alot.

Answer (score 0):

***Code in swift 3.1:***

Just in case if someone needs to copy paste it for the purpose of testing.

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Test"
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }
}
```